# Selecting multiple images from the private app directory using ELCImage Picker Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Right now, the function of the **ELC Image Picker Controller** is to select **multiple images** from the **camera roll**. But I want it to do the same ***multi-select*** function for the **private app directory**. When I try to import the ELC functions inside the private app directory, I am not able to multi-select the pictures and even if I try to select one image, that image is shown in full screen.

So, is it possible for the **ELC Image Picker Controller** to multi-select pictures from the private app directory or it is meant only for doing the same functionality with the camera roll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELC Image Picker Controller is for library only, but not to worry, you can change data source accordingly (IT IS OPEN SOURCE) . 
But you need to take care of every aspects, like dictionaries, selection keys and everything.

Comment: But since it uses asset library function, it is designed for going directly to the photo library. So, is thr any alternative for asset library function then?